# Space invaders base deterioration

Tags: collision-detection, 2d-games

In space invaders, when an alien bullet hits your defense bases, they deteriorate  slowly. Can anybody explain how games do that?

I guess they are not using images for the bases and also not bounding rectangle collision detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialing in the wayback machine. The original space invaders used a simple bit mask to add damage to the bases. The images were just basic 1 bit images, from memory 1 byte wide and 8 bytes down (8 by 8 pixels)

To apply the damage there is a mask [0b11111001,0b11110000] that is shifted left (with carry placed in the lowest bit) then masked with the base bytes. `pixelByte &= maskByte`. Then cut out the pattern of damage. Bombs would continue hitting the base if any pixels were remaining and in the path of the bomb.

To detect a base hit a mask was also used. bombMask = 0b00000011 shifted left (or could have been looked up) to match x pos. To see if there is a hit you just AND the mask with the base bits `pixelByte & bombMask` if the result is not zero then the base has been hit.

It was all written in assembly, and for its time was a programing master piece. I still remember thinking, "How can they move so many pixels so quickly."

Today you can use the same method, but you seldom see that much effort put into detail like that. I find that modern games tend to take short cuts and just have a set lot of images to show damage.

So just take the damage count, based on a hit box, or circle, show image to illustrate damage state, healthy, minor damage, major damage, and destroyed. Easy to implement! good for the game? well that is another matter altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how it was originally done, but one way to make it work would be to have each barrier made up of a number of separate blocks, each with their own health value. If a block takes enough hits, remove it.

This should allow for the barriers to deteriorate gradually.

Edit: To clarify, you would have each barrier made up of a number of separate images (I believe they were just a flat colour in the original), and each image having a rectangle that projectiles could collide with, damaging that section of the barrier.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for that. In the original, it took 2 hits for a piece to be completely destroyed. The piece would first deteriorate slightly and then be removed with the next hit. I guess you swap images on the first hit and then remove on the 2nd.

Comment: Yeah, you could modify this however you wanted. You could even add some sort of splash damage to surrounding pieces if you'd like to change it up a little. The main part is breaking the barrier into smaller hitboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In the original space invaders, there were no more than 3 invader bombs on screen at any one time so simple rectangle collision can be okay.

The way I did it was to create the bases from individual blocks/pixels with an id. When a bomb hits a base, I get the id of the 1st pixel hit via a reversed loop which breaks at that point.

From that pixel, I counted a number of pixels up, down, left and right roughly in the shape of an explosion and removed those base pixels leaving a nice dent in the base.

The same method is used for the lazer cannon shooting up at the bases.

Unfortunately, I can't post the game code as it exceeds the max character posting limit. I have the game on Codepen but I'm not allowed to post a link without some code which is too large as stated above!

However, if you go to Codepen and do a search for space invaders it appears on the 1st page as 'Space Invaders Taito 1978'